# How to handle Two ToucheventListener calls on the same View? Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, ontouchlistener

I have a library which handles onTouchListener Events for a ImageView.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int lastAction;
        float dX = 0;
        float dY = 0;
        int DELTA = 50;
        private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
        private long pressStartTime;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And then once installing the library into my app i also wanted to set my own onTouchEvent for that ImageView.

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(new new View.OnTouchListener(){});
```

The problem is that only the library touchListener event gets called and the app one is lost/neglected. If I remove the library then the app touch event gets called.  How can I make it so that both the library and the app touchListeners are called?

Comment: Just get the OnTouchListener before set you own one and call it in your new one

Comment: @sakiM hi, but this is a library, customers should be able to call their own view.setOnTouchListener without extra code. Should i consider dispatchTouchEvent?

Comment: No exactly `customers should be able to call their own view.setOnTouchListener` if the library didn't expose a similar listener interface. Search library api and you have to do this in your own part if not exist.

Comment: Thanks guys, found the answer, I'll use composite function